# How to call a controller that is async and return Task<IHttpActionResult> directly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get the results of an action from a controller directly without doing an http request

right now instantiating the controller and calling the method trying to add the results to some item which is in an diferent type

```
// other file 
_params.Id = item.Id;
var Presponse = new ProductsController().GetProducts(_params);
item.p = Presponse;

//controller file
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("products")]
    [Compress]
    // controller method signature
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProducts(TheParams model){ 
       .... some logic ....
       Ok(results) 
    }
}
```

It says I can't implicitly convert the type, in my case to a DTO class I have, I'm expecting to get the value of the response (object) just like an HTTP Request but directly and cast it.

Comment: IHttpActionResult httpActionResult = await GetProducts(model);

Comment: Are you trying to write a unit test? All unit testing frameworks support asynchronous test methods. You could write `var Presponse =await GetProducts(_params)` in any of them, as long as you changed the method's return type to `async Task`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// You could use await if your method is async, for simplicity just Result.
  IHttpActionResult actionResult = new ProductsController().GetProducts(_params).Result;

// if your result is a Product Type
  var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Product>;
  Product product = contentResult.Content;

// Map to your DTO class for example
   ProductDto dto = new ProductDto()
   {
        Id = product.Id,
        Name = product.Name
    };
```